# Rails 5 : How to prevent multiple submission from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a beginner at coding.

I'm developing my app on Rails 5, and let users crop and upload images from client side directly to AWS s3 with [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki).

I have a problem when a user re-selects an image to crop and upload.
This re-selection causes multiple form submission to rails, which ending up with creating the same number of posts as that of re-selections...

I'd like to know how to prevent this multiple submission.

My Javascript code is like that;

```js
$(function() {
  $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
    var fileInput    = $(elem);
    var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
    var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
    var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
    fileInput.after(barContainer);
    fileInput.fileupload({
    fileInput:       fileInput,
    url:             form.data('url'),
    type:            'POST',
    autoUpload:       false,
    formData:         form.data('form-data'),
    paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
    dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
    replaceFileInput: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    //trying to limit the number of files, but none of them works...
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    limitMultiFileUploads:1,
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,

    add: function(e, data){
      if (data.files && data.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('.preview').empty();
          $('.preview').append($('<img>').attr({// insert preview image
            src: e.target.result,
            id: "crop_img",
            title: data.files[0].name
          }));
          $('#crop_img').cropper() // initialize cropper on preview image
         };
       reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]);
       // $('#clear').show();
      };

      // tried to clear the form and file input when re-selection occurs, however, it doesn't work either...
      // $('#clear').click(function() {
      //     $('#image').val('');
      //     $('.preview').empty();
      //     $('form').reset();
      //     $(this).hide();
      //   });

      submitButton.on('click', function(){
      $('form').submit(function(){
        return false;
        });
       $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob){
          data.files[0] = new File([blob], data.files[0].name);
          data.originalFiles[0] = data.files[0];
          data.submit();
        })
     });
    },

   ...
    
    done: function(e, data) {

      // extract key and generate URL from response
      var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
      var url   = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

      // create hidden field
      var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
      form.append(input);

      //delete submit event which is false
      $('form').off('submit');
      //and submit again
      $('.directUpload').submit();
    }
    ...
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the following code is being called every time `add` is called:

```
submitButton.on('click', function(){
  $('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
    });
   $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob){
      data.files[0] = new File([blob], data.files[0].name);
      data.originalFiles[0] = data.files[0];
      data.submit();
    })
 });
```

I'm not sure how your code work. So, one solution is to update the code to this:

```
// outside add function:
var lastData = null;

submitButton.on('click', function(){
  $('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
    });
   $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob){
      lastData.files[0] = new File([blob], data.files[0].name);
      lastData.originalFiles[0] = lastData.files[0];
      lastData.submit();
    })
 });

 // In add function
 lastData = data;
```

PS: lastData is like a fast workaround but I don't think it will work properly.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
    var fileInput    = $(elem);
    var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
    var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
    var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);

    var lastData = null;
    submitButton.on('click', function(){
      $('form').submit(function(){
        return false;
      });
     $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob){
        lastData.files[0] = new File([blob], data.files[0].name);
        lastData.originalFiles[0] = lastData.files[0];
        lastData.submit();
      })
    });

    fileInput.after(barContainer);
    fileInput.fileupload({
    fileInput:       fileInput,
    url:             form.data('url'),
    type:            'POST',
    autoUpload:       false,
    formData:         form.data('form-data'),
    paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
    dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
    replaceFileInput: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    //trying to limit the number of files, but none of them works...
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    limitMultiFileUploads:1,
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,

    add: function(e, data){
      if (data.files && data.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('.preview').empty();
          $('.preview').append($('<img>').attr({// insert preview image
            src: e.target.result,
            id: "crop_img",
            title: data.files[0].name
          }));
          $('#crop_img').cropper() // initialize cropper on preview image
         };
       reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]);
       // $('#clear').show();
      };

      // tried to clear the form and file input when re-selection occurs, however, it doesn't work either...
      // $('#clear').click(function() {
      //     $('#image').val('');
      //     $('.preview').empty();
      //     $('form').reset();
      //     $(this).hide();
      //   });

      lastData = data;
    },

   ...
    
    done: function(e, data) {

      // extract key and generate URL from response
      var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
      var url   = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

      // create hidden field
      var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
      form.append(input);

      //delete submit event which is false
      $('form').off('submit');
      //and submit again
      $('.directUpload').submit();
    }
    ...
    });
  });
});
```